# Turn off case sensitive on CRM Oracle On Demand

Tags: php, oracle, crm

I'm using CRM Oracle On Demand and i have a problem with the case sensitive.

Here you can see a request :

```
"ContactWS_ContactQueryPage_Input" => array(
                        "ListOfContact" => array(
                            "Contact" => array(
                                "ContactId" => "",
                                "ContactFullName" => "",
                                "ContactFirstName" => "='".$firstname."'",
                                "ContactLastName" => "='".$lastname."'",
                                "CellularPhone" => "",
                                "WorkPhone" => "",
                                "WorkFax" => "",
                                "PrimaryCountry" => "",
                                "PrimaryZipCode" => "",
                                "PrimaryCity" => "",
                                "MrMrs" => "",
                                "JobTitle" => "",
                                "PrimaryAddress" => "",
                                "ContactEmail" => "",
                                "ContactType" => ""
                            )
                        ),
                        "PageSize" => "100"         
                    )
```

If for example, in my Oracle Database i have an user like :

```
First Name : TOTO
Last Name : TATA
```

And i try to do a request with : 
`$firstname = "toto"` OR `$lastname = "tAtA"`

The CRM return to me nothing, it can not find the user.

Is there a way to turn off case sensitive ? Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
alter session set nls_comp=ansi;
alter session set nls_sort=binary_ci;
```

Just beware, this can have an impact on performance. Some indexes will possibly not be used.

PS: you can also use the option: NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI when creating an index.